# Angular socket.io factory

Tags: angularjs, sockets, socket.io, angular-services, angularjs-factory

Hi i am working on a chat app and i am following socket factory pattern from http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/
But i am facing a problem in that code. we have defined the connection based on authentication. In the socket factory  he has defined this connection when the app loads . But according to my definition. after a connect the socket should emit a authentication key . which i will emit after login . But since connection has been made before login . The socket get disconnected so please help me with my problem

```
  var socket = io.connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement an 'auth' event, so that your server.js looks kinda like that:

```
module.exports = function (socket) {
    socket.on('auth', fuction(credentials) {
        if(checkCredentials(credentials)) {
            socket.emit('loggedin', { token: 'foo' });
            socket.on('send:message', sendingStuff);

            // ... register your events here
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: the problem is server has set timeout if the connection does auth within 5 sec . the socket gets disconnects. So when app loads and socket gets connected . but since user has not logged in . the auth signal will not reach the server